# next_posts_link URL does not include name of custom post type

Tags: permalinks, pagination

Inside my index.php, I have a new WP_Query() for a custom post type that I have named "todo".

I am trying to implement pagination for this query, so it only displays three posts, then requires to go to the next page to view more.

However, with this code after the while loop:

```
<li><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT', $todos->max_num_pages) ?></li>
```

The actual link itself is bringing me to `localhost/page/2.`

When it should be bringing me to `localhost/todo/page/2`, as when I enter this URL manually, it does show me the three next posts, instead of the other URL which brings me to a 404.

I am very new to Wordpress and may be missing some key details for this question, as well as some fundamental knowledge of how things work, but if anyone know's what I am doing wrong I would appreciate any help..

Below is the entire code:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else { $paged = 1; }

$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'post_type'   => 'todo',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'page' => $paged
 );
 
$todos = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

    <main id="primary" class="site-main">
        <section class="glass">
            <div class="todolist">
            <?php
            if( $todos->have_posts() ) :
                while($todos->have_posts()) :
                $todos->the_post();
            ?>
                <div class="todo">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/event_note-24px'?>" alt="">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h2><?php echo get_the_title();?></h2>
                        <div class="time">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/query_builder-24px'?>" alt="">
                            <?php echo get_the_content();?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="todoaction">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/done-24px'?>" alt="">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/clear-24px'?>" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </div>
            <li><?php previous_posts_link( ' PREV', $todos->max_num_pages) ?></li> 
            <li><?php next_posts_link( 'NEXT', $todos->max_num_pages) ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </section>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is actually the expected output of [`next_posts_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_posts_link/), i.e. *it always uses the current page URL*. And the same also applies to [`previous_posts_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_posts_link/).

So if you're on the homepage (`localhost/`), then the URL of page 2 would be `localhost/page/2`, and if you're on (your custom post type archive page at) `localhost/todo`, then the URL of page 2 would be `localhost/todo/page/2`.

And *if you want to alter the main WordPress query on the homepage, then you should use the [`pre_get_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) instead of making a secondary/custom `WP_Query` call (`new WP_Query()`)* in your `index.php` template.

So for example, to display 3 `todo` posts on the homepage,

1. Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

   ```php
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );
   function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
       // If we're on the homepage, query 3 "todo" posts instead of the default ones.
       if ( is_home() ) {
           $query->set( 'post_type', 'todo' ); // query posts of the "todo" type only
           $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 ); // and display three posts per page
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then in your `index.php` template, just remove those `$todos` and `$args`, and use the default loop to display the posts returned via the main query:

   ```
   <?php
   // No need for the $todos and $args.
   ?>

       <main id="primary" class="site-main">
           <section class="glass">
               <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                   <div class="todolist">
                       <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                           <div class="todo">
                               ... your code.
                           </div>
                       <?php endwhile; ?>
                   </div>

                   ... your pagination here.
               <?php endif; // end have_posts() ?>
           </section>
   ```

That way, even if `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` do not add the `todo/` to the pagination links, you wouldn't get the error 404 when going to `localhost/page/2` unless of course if there's no page 2 for the main query.

And if you wonder what that "main" (WordPress) query is, then check the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview), specifically the part which says, "*Save the posts in the $wp_query object to be used in the WordPress Loop.*".

Also, your pagination code will show an empty bullet when there's no next/previous posts link, so to fix that, you'd want to use [`get_previous_posts_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_posts_link/) instead of `previous_posts_link()` and [`get_next_posts_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_posts_link/) instead of `next_posts_link()`. Example:

```php
<?php // this would replace the "... your pagination here." part above.

$links = '';

if ( $link = get_previous_posts_link( 'Previous Posts' ) ) {
    $links .= "<li>$link</li>";
}

if ( $link = get_next_posts_link( 'Next Posts' ) ) {
    $links .= "<li>$link</li>";
}

if ( $links ) {
    echo "<ul>$links</ul>";
}
?>
```

Additionally, in your `$args` array, you should've used `paged` (note the "d") and not `page`, i.e. `'paged' => $paged`. But I'm just saying that so you know the correct arg is `paged`. :)

Comment: Thank you so much.